# Simple Unity Animation Not Working- What Am I doing Wrong? (FullScreenshots)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

-Says "Parameter [name of animation] does not exist " as a warning in the console
Will play initial animation, so I know the Animation Controller is functioning

Please see attached image for the full spread of VS, AC, Scene, Inspector on obj w/ script&animator:

[Visual Studio AnimationTrigger + Unity w AnimationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBYyO.png)

I've tried everything
Including creating a whole new bare-bones project
I've copied the name directly from the Animator
I've copied the name directly from the specific animation in 'Edit'
I've tried multiple animations
I've renamed the animation and tried with the re-name
I've put everything directly into the script instead of 'public'
reviewed tutorials
tried different characters/meshes with completely different animations

I've made animation triggers before and had no issue, so this is driving me absolutely mental! I must be missing one small things

Please, help if you are able

Comment: those boxes are not triggers but states, so you cant just say trigger one, without making a parameter, and linking everything up so that on trigger it knows to go to that state

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a parameter of type Trigger to true. you are not playing the animation **if you want to play the animation directly do `animator.Play(yourAnimationName);`.**

I made a small example for you to understand how triggers work [image]

as you can see i have a trigger called FadeOut  , and an arrow (transition) between 2 states The fade in state and the fade out state , the transition will only happen if The Trigger (FadeOut) is true and the way you set fade out to true in code like this `yourAmimatorComponent.SetTrigger("FadeOut");` if you want to call fade out instantly you can play it `yourAmimatorComponent.Play("FadeOut");`

[image]

Comment: omg, thank you! I knew it was something silly like that